# how to validate minimum age in webform

Tags: 6, webforms, forms

I've got a question about webform and webform validation.

I'm in D6.19 with webform 6.x-3.4 and webform validation 6.x-1.3

I'm adding a date field to capture age, and I need to validate that the age of the user is at least 13 years from current date.

Does anyone know how I can do this?
Thanks
Stephanie

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? If you use form validation, then the webform cannot be submitted until the field value is correct (in this case now - 13 years). If you are trying to block access to users under 13, then a different approach is required, say webform rules, or using a date field on user registration (again using rules). Please give us more details on your intent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I absolutely intend to prohibit users younger than 13 from submitting the form. I'll check out Webform Rules. Thanks!

Comment: Then you definitely do not want field validation. That would keep presenting the form to the user until they entered a value which passed the validation. You need to let them submit it with the entered date, then slap their wrists for doing so :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the hook_webform_submission_presave() exposed by the Webform api in a custom module.

Another alternative is to make use of this [sandbox project](https://drupal.org/sandbox/vernond/1667748)

> This module provides a way to calculate values for Webform components
>   and/or to add custom validation code without the need for creating
>   custom modules that implement hooks. It offers a PHP-like macro
>   scripting language to use instead.
>
> Differs from Webform PHP in that there is no eval() evil and macro
>   code has no direct access to Drupal environment or functions, i.e.
>   macro code is contextually jailed.
>
> Differs also from Webform Calculator in that it permits logic-driven
>   calculations and also integrates with the Webform Validation module.